# How to create a login form in Android with Support All Devices?

Tags: android

I want to create a login form. But i am new in android so i am not able to do it properly. I have to put the logo of the company on it's header. After that the heading will be Like Login to you are account after that in a box the user name and password. So i am posting my xml please upadte it. Thanks...

Comment: Where is your XML?  How to ask a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Android studio has a default login layout you can use.

Comment: sounds good . its very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> show us what you tried first. To get support on all devices, first study Layouts in Android. Then only you can be able to design a screen which is supported on most of the devices.